# Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'manticore'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am trying to run a jruby rails app locally and bundler throws me the following error

> Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the
> gem 'manticore'.

My `$bundle install` was successful and `$gem list` confirmed that the gem exists in my local environment.

> manticore (0.5.2 java)

Not sure why it is failing to load the gem!?

> Ruby - "jruby-1.7.16.1"
>
> Java - "1.8.0_40"

Comment: can you post your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the gem and see if it loads.

1. Remove manticore gem from your Gemfile.
2. Do a "gem uninstall manticore"
3. Add manticore to gemfile again and perform a "bundle install"
4. run jruby with bundle exec

Comment: I still see the same issue, even after trying this :(